# How To Create Tri-state Actions on Menus Using Qt

Tags: qt

I have a situation where I need a tri-state checkable action on a `QMenu`, and the `QAction` class appears to only support on or off, unless I'm overlooking something obvious. The situation I have is a context menu where multiple objects are selected, but may have different states for a given boolean condition (i.e. for a given property, some objects have a true value and some false). I can leave the action unchecked when there's a mix of values, but I feel that's misleading to the user.

I'm using Qt 5.5.1 and very experienced with Qt, but not seeing a way to achieve what I want in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct way to do it from a `QAction`, but it is possible to subclass the `QWidgetAction` and create an action that contains a `QCheckBox` widget.

```
class CheckBoxAction : public QWidgetAction {
public:
    CheckBoxAction (const QString &text) : QWidgetAction(Q_NULLPTR) {
        QHBoxLayout *_layout = new QHBoxLayout(Q_NULLPTR);
        QWidget *_widget = new QWidget(Q_NULLPTR);
        QLabel *_label = new QLabel(text);
        mCheckbox = new QCheckBox(Q_NULLPTR);
        _label->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
        _layout->addWidget(mCheckbox);
        _layout->addWidget(_label);
        _layout->addStretch();
        _widget->setLayout(_layout);

        setDefaultWidget(_widget);
    }

    QCheckBox *checkbox() {
        return mCheckbox;
    }

private:
    QCheckBox *mCheckbox;
};
```

Simply use the class to then add to your menu; for instance:

```
CheckBoxAction *checkAction = new CheckBoxAction(QStringLiteral("My Action"));
checkAction->checkbox()->setCheckState(Qt::PartiallyChecked);
menu->addAction(checkAction);
```

You can use the `checkbox()` method in order to connect to signals when it changes; or change the checkbox state. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I'm accepting it, but I've decided to go another route because of appearance. This doesn't look good in a QMenu, but I think it would be fine on a toolbar. I'm subclassing QAction, adding a Qt::CheckState member, and then changing the icon based on the state. This is working better, although I can't find the icon used by QAction when they're checked so that I can match it exactly.

Comment: Ah, that's also a good way to do it. Good luck! I believe the checkbox is OS specific but I could be wrong